# how to update order of images in a gallery, when image can belong to many galleries

Tags: laravel

I first designed my app to have images only belong to one gallery and for that it was enough to have order column in the images table, but now I decided I want images to be able to belong to many galleries and have redesigned my tables. These are tables I have

> galleries
>
> images
>
> gallery_image

this is how gallery_image table looks:

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->biginteger('gallery_id')->unsigned();
        $table->biginteger('image_id')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('order')->unsigned()->default(0);
        
        $table->foreign('gallery_id')->references('id')->on('galleries')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

I have moved order from the image table to the gallery_image table and need to be able to update it when I reorder images inside a gallery using javascript.

This was my code to reorder images before:

```
    $order = 1;
    foreach ($request->order as $key => $id) {
        $image = Image::where('id', $id)->first();
        $image->order = $order;
        $image->save();
        $order = $order + 1;
    }
```

But how would I reorder them now? If I have an array of image id's in the order I want them, how do I loop through images and update order column which is stored inside gallery_image table?

My models look like this:

Gallery.php

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class, 'gallery_image');
}
```

Image.php

```
public function galleries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class, 'gallery_image');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eloquent allows you to work with pivot tables similarly to how you would a regular model (in fact a pivot model extends a regular Eloquent model). Add `withPivot(order)` to the relationship in your Gallery and Image models. This tells Eloquent to use the column 'order' on the `gallery_image table`.

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class)->withPivot('order');
}
```

Now you can access the attribute on the pivot table like

```
foreach (Gallery::find(1)->images()->get() as $image) {
    echo $image->pivot->order;
}
```

and update the value like so

```
Gallery::find(1)->images()->updateExistingPivot($imageId, [
    'order' => $order,
]);
```

Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

From there you can decide how you want to implement the sorting logic. You can optimize your current implementation by taking this line `$image = Image::where('id', $id)->first();` out of the loop and instead doing a `$images = Image::findMany($request->order)` first and then looping. Having the database call inside the loop means it gets hit O(n) times instead of just once O(1).

If you absolutely need to make database calls inside of a loop then I wrote a small tool that will let you batch load entities https://github.com/andrewdalpino/DataLoader-PHP